# calculate the percentage of workers getting wages between $22$ and $58.$

Tags: frequency

I want to calculate the percentage of workers getting wages between $22$ and $58.$ I don't know what to use. Please help me. 
I've learned central tendency and interpolation.

$$\begin{cases}Wages&&No~of~Workers\\0-10&&20\\10-20&&45\\20-30&&85\\30-40&&160\\40-50&&70\\50-60&&55\\60-70&&35\\70-80&&30\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hello, user36649, and welcome to the site!  In this case, there are several plausible ways the percentage could be calculated; we'd need to know what your professor (I assume this is for a class, and you really should add the "homework" or "self-study" tag as appropriate) has already taught you.  Perhaps you could expand upon the question to fill in the gaps for those of us who aren't familiar with the content of the course.

Comment: I've learned central tendency and interpolation.

Comment: @jbowman `homework` simply maps to `self-study` anyway. This has been the case for quite a long time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no precise way.

My suggestion would be to

1. draw a cumulative frequency graph on some graph paper,
2. attempt to join the dots with a smooth freehand curve,
3. read off your interpolated cumulative figures at $22$ and $58$,
4. use the difference as your estimate of the number of workers earning between the two amounts, and
5. divide by the total number of workers

If your answer to (4) is $342$ or slightly more then you are probably on the right track